# Extract first item from enumerable <list customers>

Tags: c#, linq

I am new to LINQ/C#.  I have an enumerable list:

```
System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Collections.Generic.List>
```

I would like to extract the first item from each list and place that in a new list:

```
System.Collections.Generic.List
```

For example

```
List<customers> = from myEnumerable
                  select item[0];
```

What would be the correct way to form the linq query to extract element 0 from each list in the enumerable?

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What would be the correct way to form the linq query to extract element 0 from each list in the enumerable?

```
IEnumerable<List<T>> input = ...;
var result = input.Select(l => l[0]).ToList();
```

Comment: Awesome that worked perfect!  It picks up the first item from each list in IEnumerable. Thank you Blindy.